# Unsupported config option for services service: 'chrome'

Tags: python, selenium, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a selenium grid with docker using [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/distributed-testing-with-selenium-grid/) blog

But when i try to run **docker-compose up -d**

It is giving me error as: Unsupported config option for services service: 'chrome'
 my **docker-compose.yml** is

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-yttrium
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-yttrium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-yttrium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Docker version shows :

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.39 (downgraded from 1.40)
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea838
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:29:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your docker-compose.yml file and it works without any issues.

Possible reasons for your issue could be

1. incorrect yaml format or incorrect indentation
2. outdated docker-compose version in which case you need to upgrade to a more recent version to use the version 3 format configuration files

my docker compose configuration -

```
[root@allselenium ~]# docker-compose version
 docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
 docker-py version: 2.6.1
 CPython version: 3.6.8
 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when you try to use a compose file option that is incompatible with the engine version you are trying to run against.

Please find more information on this here:

https://success.docker.com/article/error-unsupported-config-option-for-services

And here is the compatibility matrix:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix

According to this you should have Compose File format of 3.8